# Chart.js one label per stacked bar

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

I'm using chart.js with datalabels plugin but I'm having issues with displaying one label per stacked bar.

I have tried to access to the dataset meta to distinguish to show the labels but struggling to achieve. Help me to do that. 
Please see my example here: https://jsfiddle.net/fraserr/9ezggxx5/314/

```
var datasets = JSON.parse('[{"username":"test name","stack":"2","label":"test name - actual","dataset":{"2018-12-17":"3","2018-12-24":"1"},"data":["3","1"],"borderColor":"#db005f","backgroundColor":"#f190b0","borderWidth":1},{"username":"test name","stack":"2","label":"test name - target","dataset":{"2018-12-17":"10","2018-12-24":"10"},"data":["10","10"],"borderColor":"#511158","backgroundColor":"#aa89ab","borderWidth":1},{"username":"Santa Claus","stack":"1","label":"Santa Claus - actual","dataset":{"2018-12-17":"2","2018-12-24":0},"data":["2",0],"borderColor":"#db005f","backgroundColor":"#f190b0","borderWidth":1},{"username":"Santa Claus","stack":"1","label":"Santa Claus - target","dataset":{"2018-12-17":"2","2018-12-24":"2"},"data":["2","2"],"borderColor":"#511158","backgroundColor":"#aa89ab","borderWidth":1}]');

new Chart('chart', {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['2018-12-17', '2018-12-24'],
    datasets: datasets
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          suggestedMax: 50
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: true
      }]
    },
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        formatter: (value, ctx) => {
          return ctx.dataset.username;
        },
        align: 'end',
        anchor: 'end',
      }
    }
  }
});
```

My desired result is to have "test name" on at the top of the 1st bar, "Santa Claus" on the 2nd, "test name" on 3rd and "Santa Claus" on 4th.  Ideally I would always show one label per bar (even when one is bar per stack is hidden).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think it should be better to show those labels in the legend (The color squares above). The way you got it is confusing, you have four different things with the same colors, maybe with four different colors I wouldn't see the need to add the Datalabels.